# Clang with CLion: Cannot get compiler information

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clion, azerothcore

I tried to switch from gcc to clang in CLion by changing the **Toolchains** preference:

[image: clang clion]

But now the cmake fails with the following:

```
Cannot get compiler information:
Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/bin/clang++ -xc++ -DENABLE_EXTRAS ...
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0
```

If I manually run CMake in a terminal using `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++` then it will work, only in CLion it doesn't.

Comment: Could you please include the command, CLion is executing!? It's the (blue) line right above your error log.

Comment: @StanleyF. sorry what blue line?

Comment: In the panel where you got the error output (CMake or Messages panel), scroll to the top. [There you will find the command, CLion is executing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pp23.png)

Answer (score 3):

Using clang 6.0 solves the problem:

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang-6.0
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++-6.0
```

in CMake Options and go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.
Everything works normal.

Comment: thanks for sharing that, however in my case I was already using clang 6 (the default version of Ubuntu 18.04)